# Use AllJoyn Unity Extension

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, alljoyn

I need help integrating AllJoyn Unity Extension in my Unity project. I have managed to acquire SDK and create a unitypackage file and add it to my project. However compiling it just give me a DLL not found Exception "alljoyn_unity.dll not found" SDK is v14.12.

However connecting Unity console to Visual Studio I get a warning that mscorlib has higher version and namespace AllJoynUnity cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your project .Net version is not lower than what the unity plugin requires